# Nobody ever went broke underestimating the intelligence of the American people?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Was H. L. Mencken the first to say 'Nobody ever went broke underestimating the intelligence of the American people.", or was he paraphrasing another comentator?

Comment: Now why are you asking this question today? :)

Comment: Don't forget P. T. Barnum: “Nobody ever lost a dollar by underestimating the taste of the American public.”

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with the English language.

Comment: @DanBron Absolutely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [ThisDayinQuotes.com](http://www.thisdayinquotes.com/) in the September 19, 1926 edition of the *Chicago Daily Tribune*...in [his] column “Notes on Journalism” what [Mencken](http://www.thisdayinquotes.com/2011/09/no-one-ever-went-broke-underestimating.html) actually said was:

> No one in this world, so far as I know — and I have searched the
>   records for years, and employed agents to help me — has ever lost
>   money by underestimating the intelligence of the great masses of the
>   plain people. Nor has anyone ever lost public office thereby.

The source says:

> Over time, this longer quote came to be paraphrased and misquoted,
>   most commonly in the form “No one ever went broke underestimating the
>   intelligence of the American public.”

The specific link is to [Mencken](http://www.thisdayinquotes.com/2011/09/no-one-ever-went-broke-underestimating.html)